# C++ multiple type assignment

Tags: c++

I not very familiar with C++, have some issues with the multiple assignments

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
```

works

```
int i;
double d;
char c;
c = i = d = 42;
```

also works
but why this does not works.

```
int a = 4, float b = 4.5, bool ab = TRUE;
```

Comment: It doesn't work because those are the rules of C++.  Differing types cannot be declared in a single line like that.

Comment: Because the language was designed that way: you can only declare multiple variables with the same base type. Also note that your `bool` should be `true`, not `TRUE`.

Comment: But `int a = 4; float b = 4.5; bool ab = true; // in one line` works.

Comment: @CEPB Why? It's `d = 42; i = d; c = i;`.

Comment: @CEPB Yes, and the result is well defined.

Comment: @CEPB _"I think `c = i = d = 42;` is UB"_ no, this is well defined. _"What if you do `c = i = d = 55555`"_ yes, that's UB if it causes a signed overflow. For unsigned wrap around it's still well defined. `char` can be unsigned or signed. It implementation defined.

Comment: Thanks, so it is the language rule, I see. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: @jabaa Thanks, I see now

Comment: @CEPB No, that's well defined. `int i = 42.0` and `char c = 42.0` are well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with the allowed syntax. The format is, in very high-level terms, roughly:

```cpp
type varName [ = expr ][, varName [ = expr ] ]?;
```

Where there is no allowance at all for another type to be introduced mid-stream.

In practice declaring multiple variables per line can lead to a lot of ambiguity and confusion.

Quick quiz: What is the initial value of `a`? What type is `b`?

```cpp
int* a, b = 0;
```

If you guessed `a` was a NULL pointer and `b` was `int*` you'd be wrong. This is why it's often preferable to spell it out long-form so there's absolute clarity:

```cpp
int* a;
int b = 0;
```